# Using GIMP, what is the easiest way to repeat an image in a tiled fashion?

Tags: gimp, image-processing

I have an image that is 100×125 pixels in size.

I'd like to create a new image by repeating the source image, five times, horizontally (so the new image is 500×125px).

The repetitions must be pixel perfect, in exactly the right place (so I'm less likely to accept an answer that requires placement by eye-balling).

What's the easiest way to do this using GIMP?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

1. In the menu, navigate: **`Filters → Map → Tile...`**.
2. Disconnect vertical and horizontal scales (break the "chain" between them).
3. Switch the units to percentage (%).
4. Enter `500%` for the width, `100%` for the height.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There is no need to switch to percentage.

Comment: @iglvzx isnt % a cleaner option ?

Comment: @shark, Yes! Misread the question, I mixed up their original height and width. I will fix it! Forgive my rashness...

Comment: Magnificent! Even easier than I expected. Thank you!

Comment: is it normal that it takes more than 5 minutes for gimp to do the tiling from an 1x355 px image to an 1200x355 px one, on a dualcore machine ? any browser does that in <1 seconds! to answer myself: the step i skipped by accident is to "disconnect the Chain". now it takes < 5 *seconds*. :)

Comment: If you don't unlink the two values you may adjust the other value without realising, and for example, it might go from a 1x355px image to a 1200x426000 image. That could take over 5 minutes to process!

Comment: A nice feature would be selecting a template size (like A4, A3, Letter etc.) so that we can easily create a page for printing.

Answer (score 8):

Don't have GIMP at hand right now but have you tried:
**`Filters > Map > Tile`**?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to sastanin's answer, you'll want to

1. Go to the menu and click: **`Filters → Map → Tile...`**.
2. Disconnect vertical and horizontal scales by breaking the little "chain" icon between them,
3. Set width to `500` and height to `125`.
4. Hit `OK`.

There is no need to set units to percentages. I actually recommend against this because if you do want to switch the height to something other than 125 px later, it can get a bit mathy (not too difficult, but it can be avoided.)

Comment: Thank you for this modern solution, built in.